# Linux: Chilispot or FreeRadius

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.04, radius

Has anybody installed Chilispot or FreeRadius on Ubuntu?
If yes, where are the traps? How is your experience?

Peace

Ice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done so on Ubuntu, but I did run our original wireless implementation on a CentOS box running chillispot/freeradius/dd-wrt. It wasn't horribly difficult to setup and management was fairly reasonable. While it wasn't tied to our AD infrastructure, it was fairly simple to add/manage users and guests could be created with an account that automatically timed out.

Comment: Seems to be a sunday afternoon job. AD is no issue but there are some other questions like how looks the whole layout from wlan-client -> WLan-AccesPoint -> switch -> firewall -> internet. where to install the chilispot/freeradius/dd-wrt?

Comment: Ours was a standard dd-wrt install on an older Linksys WAP and the chillispot/freeradius install on an old Dell workstation. I googled to see if I could find the directions I used, but dd-wrt+chillispot+freeradius comes back with almost 14k results.